# Pyramid subscriber predicates not working

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid 1.4a1 and I have this subscriber predicate:

```
class RouteName(object):
    '''
    Subscriber predicate to check against route name.
    '''

    def __init__(self, value, config):
        self.value = value
        self.config = config

    def text(self):
        return 'route_name = %s' % self.value
    phash = text

    def __call__(self, event):
        route_name = event.request.matched_route.name
        return route_name == self.value
```

And I add it like so:

```
config.add_subscriber_predicate('route_name', RouteName)
```

However, whenever I try to use it, like so:

```
@subscriber(ContextFound, route_name='user.register')
def check_invitation(event):
    # Check invitation token before running registration view code ...
```

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/bin/pserve", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.4a1', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 47, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 290, in run
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 318, in loadapp
    return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/project/__init__.py", line 49, in main
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 955, in make_wsgi_app
    self.commit()
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 629, in commit
    self.action_state.execute_actions(introspector=self.introspector)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 1083, in execute_actions
    tb)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 1075, in execute_actions
    callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/adapters.py", line 53, in register
    order, preds, phash = predlist.make(self, **predicates)
  File "/Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/util.py", line 264, in make
    pred = predicate_factory(val, config)
pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationExecutionError: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: object.__new__() takes no parameters
  in:
  Line 80 of file /Workspace/Personal/project/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/events.py:
    config.add_subscriber(wrapped, iface, **self.predicates)
```

I also have a custom view predicate registered in the same manner, and it works just fine, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your code somewhere.  The following application
works under 1.4a1.  If you visit / it prints checked.  If you visit /another,
it does not:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.events import subscriber, ContextFound
from pyramid.view import view_config

class RouteName(object):
    '''
    Subscriber predicate to check against route name.
    '''

    def __init__(self, value, config):
        self.value = value
        self.config = config

    def text(self):
        return 'route_name = %s' % self.value

    phash = text

    def __call__(self, event):
        route_name = getattr(event.request.matched_route, 'name', None)
        return route_name == self.value

@subscriber(ContextFound, route_name='home')
def check(event):
    print 'checked'

@view_config(renderer='string', route_name='home')
def home(request):
    return 'home'

@view_config(renderer='string', route_name='another')
def another(request):
    return 'another'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_subscriber_predicate('route_name', RouteName)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('another', '/another')
    config.scan()
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```